# PHPunit Symfony exits 255 without --process-isolation

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a Symfony 3 app and I'm trying to run functional tests with PHPunit where I load in fixtures on every test.

Currently, the test will fail silently with a code of 255, with no output or logs present as to why it fails. Even after I have exhausted all possible configurations of PHP to try and get it to output more information.

If I run the failing test by itself, it passes fine.
If I run the whole suite at once it will fail.
If I remove the failing test, it will still fail on the test after that.

The only way it passes is with the --process-isolation flag, but that significantly slows down the tests.

Relevant php.ini configs:

```
memory_limit = -1
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
```

Has anyone had any similar issues and may know of a solution?

Comment: PHPUnit may return with an error code but without any output. It happens when a class is not found by the autoloader, for example. You should look your system logs for the error messages from PHP, as you set the `log_errors` option to `On`.

Comment: There's nothing in the log_errors file :(

Comment: I added an answer as I already faced this issue.

Comment: Some clarification are needed: you wrote "the test will fail silently with a code of 255". Saying a test is _failing_ means the test run but the assertion are not validated. I think you would say that "the test suite don't run returning a 255 error code and without any output". So, if you don't get any output, how can you know which test cause the crash (as you wrote "If I run the failing test by itself, it passes fine.") ?

Comment: For example: If I've got 20 tests, PHPUnit will run up until the 10th test and  exit 255. If I remove the 10th test, it will still exit 255 at the same point.

Comment: OK! It's seems to be a memory or function invocation depth limit which is reached. Using the `--process-isolation` runs a new  `php` process for each test. The 10th test has not to be blamed. **Try to run only the 9th first tests.**

Comment: As you set the `memory_limit` to -1, it can't be a memory limit reached. It should be some recursive function call which does not end up. A 255 error code is a PHP error. But I don't understand why you don't get any output !

Comment: @shariff9876: can you share some information on the web (using Pastebin for example): the output of your test run (using the `--debug` option of PHPUnit), the output of the `php --ini` command and the output of the `php -i` command ? Feel free to filter the data you post as some commands will output a lot of data which may expose some private information !

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit may return with an error code but without any output. It happens when a PHP error occurs and that the errors are not configured to be shown.

You should look your system logs for the error messages from PHP, as you set the `log_errors` directive to `On`.

## If the logs are empty

First, you have to check that the `php.ini` file you expect to be loaded is the right one.

Depending on your system, PHP may load [a different configuration file for CGI/CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php).

You can also use the following command to show the loaded configuration file while in CLI:

```
$ php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/php-cli.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Then, you need to check the [`error_log` configuration directive](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) as it defines where the logs are written.

Comment: I did everything you said, and still there is nothing in the logs

Comment: And why would it not be able to find a class only without --process-isolation?

Comment: Not found class is just an example. More generally, PHP errors occurring before PHPUnit is initialized don't let it show the error in the terminal. It's just a behavior I noticed when there is a typo on one of my class name.